# Why didn't the blaster bolt fall to the ground when kylo ren released it?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

Why didn't it fall? It lost it's inertia when he froze it in place.

Comment: Gotta agree with Cheese. The other answer gives the best explanation you're likely to get, given that the physics aren't real.